# Display Tab Content Immediately On Page Load

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a cinema website (school assignment) with three tabs: "Now Showing", "Coming Soon", "Promotions". I would like all content under "Now Showing" to be immediately visible upon page load. What do I need to edit in the HTML + Javascript code to do this?

I have only learnt HTML & CSS so far and adapted the Javascript code from w3schools. Hence, I'm not sure what to do. Thank you.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div id="tab-rows">

<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'now- 
showing')">Now Showing</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'coming- 
soon')">Coming Soon</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 
'promotions')">Promotions</button>
</div>

<div id="now-showing" class="tabcontent">
<p>Placeholder Content</p> 
</div>
<div id="coming-soon" class="tabcontent">
<p>Placeholder Content</p>
</div>
<div id="promotions" class="tabcontent">
<p>Placeholder Content</p>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript code.

```
<script>
  function openContent(evt, contentName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" 
          active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(contentName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

1. You could use the `onload` in the html and call your `openContent` function in it.
2. If you would wish to do it with the javascript only you can add event listener have to pass in your `openContent` as the second argument `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", openContent);`

Comment: Thank you! However, I am not familiar with JS at all so am unable to implement your solution successfully. Will try down the road once I learn it in my course :)

Answer (score 0):

You could change:

```
<div id="now-showing" class="tabcontent">
```

to:

```
<div id="now-showing" class="tabcontent active">
```

and add this to `<head>`:

```
<style>
  .tabcontent { display: none; }
  .tabcontent.active { display: block; }
  .tablinks.active { cursor: not-allowed; }
</style>
```

and update your script like:

```
function openContent(evt, contentName) {

  var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (var i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].classList.remove("active");
  }

  var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }

  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  document.getElementById(contentName).classList.add("active");
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLVQmp

Comment: Thank you and fantastic! It works! If you don't mind helping me out with one more question: how do I make the "Now Showing" button a different colour when the page loads? At the moment, all buttons are black; if you hover or click on them it will turn grey. I would like the grey colour for "Now Showing" to appear upon loading. The CSS code for an active button is as below in my script. Thank you so much!

`.tab button.active {
    background-color: #5F5B5B;
}`

Comment: Glad to be of aid. I updated the codepen link with those new requirements.